# Executing a for loop after one is finished in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Server response returning three JSON arrays and all the objects are stored in database one by one and `optionsGroupList`, `attributes`, `assignedattributes`. 
In the Project I have three tables are named as a `group`, `attribute`, and `assignedattribute`. firstly I have to insert all the elements of optionsGroupList in group table and I'm able to do so, In the second array I'm getting `groupid`, `attributeid`, `attributename` but in the second table I have 4 columns which have
`groupid`, `attributeid`,`attributename`,`groupname`, but for the  groupname I have to get the record of a particular group by group id from group table but my second loop executes first so I'm not able to get the group record because of the loop still inserting records that time my second loop has started before completing first, my second table depends on the first and my third table depends on the second so I need to insert record after one is finished. Sometimes it works correctly

```
{
    "result": 1,
    "data": "optionsList",
    "merchantid": "MER-07156",
    "optionsGroupList": [{
        "grouprowid": "3012",
        "groupname": "Color",
        "isrequired": "0"
    }],
    "attributes": [{
        "attributerowid": "20794",
        "grouprowid": "3012",
        "attributename": "Red",
        "weight": "0"
    }],
    "assignedattributes": [{
            "attributegrouprowid": "154577",
            "productrowid": "342702",
            "attributerowid": "20794",
            "subsku": "",
            "quantity": "0",
            "pricechange": "4"
        },
        {
            "attributegrouprowid": "154590",
            "productrowid": "354723467",
            "attributerowid": "20794",
            "subsku": "0",
            "quantity": "0",
            "pricechange": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

My Second loop debug statement printing before first.

```
optionListService().then((onValue) async {
  if (onValue.result == 1) {

    //Loop 1
    for(int i=0;i<onValue.optionsGroupList.length;i++){
      _insertOption(onValue.optionsGroupList[i]);
    }

    //Loop 2
    for(int j=0;j<onValue.attributes.length;j++){
      debugPrint('Attribute Name:--${ onValue.attributes[j].attributename}');// this is printed first before first loop excuted
      List groupIdList=new List<Map<String,dynamic>>();
      groupIdList= await dbHelper.queryReadOption(onValue.attributes[j].grouprowid); // here i'm finding group name from group table but i think is executing first.

      if(groupIdList.length>0){

        _insertOptionAttribute(onValue.attributes[j],groupIdList[0][DatabaseHelper.columnGroupName],groupIdList[0][DatabaseHelper.columnIsRequired]);
      }

    }

    //Loop 3
  for(int i=0;i<onValue.assignedattributes.length;i++){

      String attr=onValue.assignedattributes[i].attributerowid;
      arrtIdList=new List<Map<String,dynamic>>();
      arrtIdList= await dbHelper.queryReadAttribute(attr);
      if(arrtIdList.length>0){

        _insertProductWithAttribute(
            onValue.assignedattributes[i],
            arrtIdList[0][DatabaseHelper.columnGroupId],
            arrtIdList[0][DatabaseHelper.columnGroupName],
            arrtIdList[0][DatabaseHelper.columnAttributeName],
            arrtIdList[0][DatabaseHelper.columnIsRequired],
            arrtIdList[0][DatabaseHelper.columnWeight]
        );
      }

    }}});}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add second loop in chained "then" block and in first block return "onValue" varibale. like so:

```
optionListService().then((onValue) async {
    if (onValue.result == 1) {

        //Loop 1
        for(int i=0;i<onValue.optionsGroupList.length;i++){
            _insertOption(onValue.optionsGroupList[i]);
        }
    }

    return onValue;

}).then((onValue) {
    if (onValue.result == 1) {
        //Loop 2
        for(int j=0;j<onValue.attributes.length;j++){
            // some code
        }
    }
});
```